# Instrumentation amplifiers in DIY EMG sensors for myography

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential

I've read a couple of articles about EMG sensors. I have seen two DIY projects so far:

[Super simple muscle (EMG) sensor](https://hackaday.io/project/8823-super-simple-muscle-emg-sensor)

[An IR muscle contraction sensor](https://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/eceprojectsland/STUDENTPROJ/2013to2014/ras578/Writeup/An%20IR%20Muscle%20Contraction%20Sensor.html)

Why are instrumentation amplifiers used in these EMG sensors?

They used INA12x - quite a good one. I thought that the main advantage of such amps is their ability to reject noise- but this can happen only if the signals on both inputs are in opposite phase.

For EMG tasks they connect the ground wire to the "bony" part of the body, and the other two wires somewhere on top of the muscle.  The difference signal is at the output of the amplifier.

I can only think that this is for a better balance of the output signal.

Comment: all opamps are differential, do you mean *instrumentation amplifiers*?

Comment: The INA128 is an Instrumentation amplifier and not an op-amp.

Comment: You are both correct, that's my problem with the terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an Instrumentation Amp, not an op amp.

They don't reject "noise" -- they reject "common mode signals".

The amplification is of the *difference* between the two inputs, and thus they attenuate (greatly) signals that are the same on both electrodes (in phase, not out of phase)

Comment: You are correct, I've had issues with the terminology.  I tried to refer to "Differential signaling", but that's irrelevant here.

So therefore I correct myself with my hopefully valid understanding.  Using instrumentation amplifiers to amplify only the difference between signal A and signal B will reject what's common in these signals. The common part may contain noise portion from the mains, etc.